# Test profile for all tests in Spring Boot?

Tags: testing, spring-boot

Is there a way to have the test profile be automatically activated for all tests in Spring Boot? I don't want to depend on class annotations or command line arguments as both are error-prone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can create application properties files in **test/resources** directory.

Just create  `/src/test/resources/application.properties` or `/src/test/resources/application.yml` file contains

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

This `application.*` file wil be used only in testing.

Comment: Thank you. Oddly, that seems to have an effect on gradle test, but not on IntelliJ running JUnit tests.